# Метод какого интерфейса будет вызван?

Tags: java

Есть вот такие интерфейсы:

```
public interface A {
    void say();
}

public interface B {
    void say();
}
```

есть класс реализующий эти интерфейсы:

```
public class Test implements A, B {

    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("SAAAY");
    }
}
```

Допустим создаем экземпляр класса и вызван метод say():

```
Test test = new Test();
test.say();
```

Метод какого интерфейса будет вызван? Как вообще работает компиляция вот этого класса?

Comment: Будет вызван тот, что имплементирован

Comment: Вот если бы один метод был void, а другой что то возвращал, была бы ошибка компиляции с:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В интерфейсе нет реализации, так что будет вызван метод из класса `Test`.

В месте вызова:

```
test.say();
```

компилятор вставит [специальную инструкцию jvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual), суть которой в том, что будет вызван метод `say` у класса объекта `test`, т.е. в данном случае метод из класса `Test`.

Comment: а есть возможность или вообще смысл понять метод какого интерфейса вызван?

Comment: Что понимаете под "вызван метод интерфейса", если у интерфейса нет реализации метода?

Comment: к какому интерфейсу будет относиться метод

Comment: Метод в классе (т.е. в представлении класса в бинарном виде, например, в *.class файле) никак не привязан к интерфейсу. В runtime точно так же в информации, которую хранит JVM (и которую можно достать через reflection из `java.lang.reflect.Method`) тоже нет информации об интерфейсе.

Comment: спасибо, понял)